# The Convert to Latest Swift Syntax of Xcode does not convert Set related code properly. Code creates opposite results

Tags: swift, set, swift2, xcode7

If you have been using Swift 1.2 and have used Sets using Set(arrayLiteral:"...") then the auto convert does not convert such operations properly. What used to pass in Swift 1.2 will fail in Swift 2.0

E.g.If your Swift 1.2 code is

```
var charsSet:Set<Character> = Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_")
if charsSet.isStrictSupersetOf(password.lowercaseString)
{
    print("true")
} else {
    print("false")
}
```

Then converting to latest Swift syntax creates this code.

```
let charsSet = Set(arrayLiteral: "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_")
let passwordSet = Set(arrayLiteral: password.lowercaseString)
if charsSet.isStrictSupersetOf(passwordSet)
{
    print("true")
} else {
    print("false")
}
```

The results will be opposite in this case. What was passing in Swift 1.2 will now fail in Swift 2.0

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The auto converted code should be changed to this.

```
//Corrected code for Swift 2.0
let charsSet2 = Set("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_".characters)
let passwordSet2 = Set(password.lowercaseString.characters)
if charsSet2.isStrictSupersetOf(passwordSet2)
{
    print("true")
} else {
    print("false")
}
```

[image]